# why and how to solve the data lost when multi encode in python pandas

Tags: python, list, encode, one-hot-encoding

[Download the Data Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y99lGWz9r-g7Kp-HvtCKUOgSOZf2xwzO?usp=sharing)

Hi, I have a data something like below, and would like to multi label the data.

something to like this: [target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK0Zr.png)

But the problem here is data lost when multilabel it, something like below:

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wxhh.png)

using the coding of:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)

df_enc = df.drop('movieId', 1).join(df.movieId.str.join('|').str.get_dummies())
```

Someone can help me, feel free to download the dataset, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that column when read in with pandas will be stored as a string. So first we'd need to convert that to an actual list.

From there use `.explode()` to expand out that list into a series (where the index will match the index it came from, and the column values will be the values in that list).

Then crosstab that from a series into each row and column being the value.

Then join that back up with the dataframe on the index values.

Keep in mind, when you do one-hot-encoding with high cardinality, you're table will blow up into a **huge** wide table. I just did this on the first 20 rows, and ended up with 233 columns. with the 225,000 + rows, it'll take a while (maybe a minute or so) to process and you end up with close to 1300 columns. This may be too complex for machine learning to do anything useful with it (although maybe would work with deep learning). You could still try it though and see what you get. What I would suggest to test out is find a way to simplify it a bit to make it less complex. Perhaps find a way to combine movie ids in a set number of genres or something like that? But then test to see if simplifying it improves your model/performance.

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv('ratings_action.csv')

df.movieId = df.movieId.apply(literal_eval)
s = df['movieId'].explode()
df = df[['userId']].join(pd.crosstab(s.index, s))
```